# Embedded objects inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array named $result, 
the output for **print_r($result)** look like this.

```
Array
(

[0] => Profile Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => alvis
        [parentLink] => ProfileLink Object
            (
                [href] => web
                [type] => data
            )
    )

[1] => Profile Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => gorgia
        [parentLink] => ProfileLink Object
            (
                [href] => text
                [type] => values
            )
    )

[2] => Profile Object
    (
        [id] => 4 
        [name] => text
        [parentLink] => ProfileLink Object
            (
                [href] => text
                [type] => values
            )
    )

 )
```

I tried displaying just the name by using:

```
foreach ($results[name] as $key => $value) {
            echo $key . ": " . $value."<br>";
            }
```

but I got an error Cannot use object of type Profile as array.

and when I tried

```
foreach ($results->name as $key => $value) {
            echo $key . ": " . $value."<br>";
            }
```

I got another error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
is there's away to display the id and the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your $result array using foreach, and then access the  "name" attribute using "->" notation.

```
    foreach ($result as $profile) {
            print $profile->name;
     }
```

If you want to get all properties of the profile object, you will have to use get_object_vars().

```
     foreach ($result as $profile) {
           $vars = get_object_vars($profile);
           foreach ($vars as $key => $var) {
                 echo $key . ": " . $var."<br>";
                 // add suitable looping for the ProfileLink object too
           }
     }
```

Comment: I used your code to get the answer! Thanks a lot,
The code was:

          $vars = get_object_vars($results);
   for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
     print_r($vars[$i]->name);
     print_r($vars[$i]->id);
   }

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` to iterate through each profile object in your array, and then reference the properties of each profile using `->`. The code below ignores the numeric index of the array and just uses the `id` and `name` from the profile object.

```
foreach ($result as $profile) {
    echo $profile->id .": ".$profile->name . " <br>";
}
```

If you want to include the numeric index of the array as well:

```
foreach ($result as $index=>$profile) {
    echo "(index ". $index .") ".$profile->id.": ".$profile->name." <br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot doublesharp for your quick response, I tried the first script and I got this output " : : : : : :" and this "(index id) : 
(index name) : " for the second script, and it didn't trough any error message. Do you have any idea what's happened. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using `$result` or `$results` - I think I incorrectly copied you variable name. I also updated my answer to not use curly braces and concatenate the string in case that matters.

Comment: That just displays the Key, not the values, I used the code that @Janenz00 suggested and I modify it and it works perfect! thanks a lot @doublesharp!
          $vars = get_object_vars($results);
   for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
     print_r($vars[$i]->name);
     print_r($vars[$i]->id);
   }